Proof of the Cantor-Bernstein-Schröder theorem by fixed point iteration
This is a proof found in the book Real Analysis by Cassio Neri. After a few days I'm still trying to understand this solution.
Do you believe that my reasoning may be correct?
Over the iterations, the elements that cause image overlap are discarded so that when we stabilize $X_0$, only the elements of this set in $f$ can remain in $f(X_0)$ and then $g^{-1}$ remains with the other remaining elements. That's why we define $\displaystyle X_0=\bigcap_{i=0}^{+\infty}F^i(A)$ in this way so that the sets fit into each other where $X_0$ is contained in each iteration. This seems like finding a fixed point of the function $f(x)=\cos x$ in the interval $[1/2,1]$.
If $\#A\leq\#B$ and $\#B\le\#A$, then $\#A=\#B$.
Before presenting the proof, let us comment on the idea of ​​the proof.
The goal is to construct a bijection $h$ from $A$ to $B$. We have at our disposal
two ingredients: a function $f$ from $A$ to $B$ and a function $g$ from $B$ to $A$,
both injective. There are, therefore, two natural "paths" that go from $A$
to $B$: $f$ and $g^{-1}$. Considering this in the definition of $h$, the problem
is reduced to deciding which points of $A$ will follow the first path and which will
follow the second. That is, we divide $A$ into two complementary parts, $X_0$
and $X_0^\complement$, and set $h=f$ in $X_0$ and $h=g^{-1}$ in $X_0^\complement$.
The function $h$ will be bijective if and only if the images of $X_0$ and $X_0^\complement$ are complementary (in $B$). That is, we must choose $X_0$ such that $f\left(X_0\right)^\complement=g^{-1}\left(X_0^\complement\right)$ or, equivalently, $g\left(f(X_0)^\complement\right)=X_0^\complement$. The
last equation is rewritten as $F(X_0)=X_0$, where $F$ is defined by:
$$F(X)=g\big(f(X)^\complement\big)^\complement.
$$
By verifying $F(X_0)=X_0$, $X_0$ is said to be a fixed point of $F$. Fixed point arguments are quite common in Analysis. The idea, intuitively, is the following. Consider a function $F:Y\rightarrow Y$ for which
we want to find a fixed point. We take $y\in Y$ and iterate $F$
"infinite" times obtaining the result $y_0$. Applying $F$ to $y_0$, we will have
as a result $F$ iterated "infinite" times, starting from $y$, that is,
we will find $y_0$ again. Therefore, $F(y_0)=y_0$. The description given here
deviates from the standards of rigor in Mathematics. The idea of ​​iterating "infinitely" many times is
formalized by taking the sequence
$$
F(y),F(F(y)),F(F(F(y))),\cdots
$$
and checking whether it tends to some element that, naturally, we expect to be
a fixed point of $F$.
Proof: By hypothesis, there exist $f:A\rightarrow B$ and $g:B\rightarrow A$ that are injective.
Consider $F:{\cal P}(A)\rightarrow{\cal P}(A)$ given by
$$
F(X)=g\big(f(X)^\complement\big)^\complement\quad\forall X\subset A.
$$
Let $\displaystyle X_0=\bigcap_{i=0}^{+\infty}F^i(A)$
(assuming that $F^0(A)=A$). Since
$f$ is injective, we have
$$
f(X_0)=f\left(\bigcap_{i=0}^{+\infty}F^i(A)\right)=\bigcap_{i=0}^{+\infty}
f\big(F^i(A)\big).
$$
Therefore,
\begin{align*}
F(X_0)&=g\left(\left(\bigcap_{i=0}^{+\infty}f\big(F^i(A)\big)\right)^\complement
\right)^\complement
=g\left(\bigcup_{i=0}^{+\infty}f\big(F^i(A)\big)^\complement\right)^\complement
=\left(\bigcup_{i=0}^{+\infty}g\left(f \big(F^i(A)\big)^\complement\right)\right)
^\complement\\
&=\bigcap_{i=0}^{+\infty}g\left(f\big(F^i(A)\big)^\complement\right)^\complement
=\bigcap_{i=0}^{+\infty}F\big(F^i(A)\big)
=\bigcap_{i=1}^{+\infty}F^i(A)
=\bigcap_{i=0}^{+\infty}F^i(A)=X_0.
\end{align*}
It follows that $X_0^\complement=F(X_0)^\complement=g\big(f(X_0)^\complement\big)$.
We conclude that $g$ is a bijection of $f(X_0)^\complement$ in $X_0^ \complement$,
hence, $g^{-1}$ is a bijection of $X_0^\complement$ in $f(X_0)^\complement$.
We also have that $f$ is a bijection of $X_0$ in $f(X_0)$. From these observations
it follows that $h:A\rightarrow B$ given by
$$
h(x)=\left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
f(x) & \text{if }x\in X_0,\\
g^{-1}(x) & \text{if }x\in X_0^\complement,
\end{array}
\right.
$$
is bijective.
In the previous demonstration it was not necessary to consider limits because it is
natural to say that a sequence of embedding sets:
$$A_1\supset A_2\supset A_3\supset\dots
$$
"converges" to $\displaystyle\bigcap_{n=1}^{+\infty}A_n$.
